# Inline Ajax call after term is appended with a @ or # etc. displayed in div

Tags: wp-query, ajax, post-content

Basically what I would like to know is how to do the following:

I have TinyMCE Advanced enabled. I would like for my users to be able to tag content with different special characters (each refer to a different taxonomy or category for example @dogs could be from animals and #blue could be from colors). The result of doing so would be a Ajax Query in a div basically displaying a search result list complete with title, excerpt, and even thumbnail pertaining to that content listing once the user tags the inline content like @dogs.

The second part is where it may get tricky. I am basically seeking to recreate google's "research" function in Google Docs where you can search for sources etc. via Google Scholar in a sidebar and without leaving the page not only browse the results, but also get an official "cite" for the article or insert the content directly into your doc.

I would like to implement all of these functionalities and I basically have came up with a plan that integrates one plugin into another plugin etc. But its not the way I would like to do it, nor does it achieve the functionality that I want. I am really really new at Ajax but I have seen similar functionalities so I think this is possible to achieve.

Comment: This is really a tinymce question and not a wordpress one, probably better to ask on tinymce forums.

Comment: I have TinyMCE enabled but I don't even know if I want to use it because I loose some functionalities from my actual WP Editor which I would like to keep. This is primarily a WP + Ajax question from what I can see.